# Add Reference Dialog missing Assemblies section in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I've been creating my first for .NET Core projects. (In this case, just a console application.) And I've noticed that when I right click on *Dependencies* and select  *Add Reference*, the dialog that appears no longer includes an *Assemblies* section.

In previous versions, this section would list all the Microsoft assemblies and include some additional information for each assembly. Now, my only option is to click the *Browse* button and see if I can find the folder that contains the correct version of the assembly I'm after.

Since this seems to be a loss of some basic functionality, I can't help but think I'm missing something here. Can anyone say why this section was removed in .NET Core? Can anyone say what is now the preferred way to add additional Microsoft assemblies to a project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but I guess it should be related to the modularity of the framework. Previously in .NET Framework you just downloaded the entire framework and has access to all the assemblies available inside the framework. That's not the case in .Net Core, because now the framework is way more modular, and everything is a Nuget Package. In case you want to add a reference to another assembly you just have to download the nuget package that contains the assembly you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The assemblies listed for .NET Framework projects come from the framework itself, and you can opt in and out of specific features that way.

For .NET Core, you get ALL the framework's assemblies included via the Framework Reference:

[image]

Therefore you don't need to opt in or out of specific assemblies in the same way as you used to.

Note too that the "Extensions" page of the "Add Assembly Reference" UI doesn't apply in .NET Core. Those extension assemblies are sourced from the Windows Registry, and .NET Core is cross-platform and cannot rely on the registry.

For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager